# A-Frame Camera rotation and movement animation not taking into account new data

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

I am trying to do make my camera move and rotate to certains positions and rotations that are dynamically given in js.

However, the camera rotates from starting value to 0 0 0. When the data says it should be other values. The rotation is done instantly, there is no animation. The position doesn't change even if the data successfully changed.

I am using the aframe-animation-component.

```
// JS
var camera = document.getElementById('camera');

camera.components.animation__movecamera.data.from = camera.components.position.data;
camera.components.animation__rotatecamera.data.from = camera.components.rotation.data;

camera.components.animation__movecamera.data.to = (positions.x - positionX)+ ' ' + positions.y + ' ' + (positions.z + 10);
camera.components.animation__rotatecamera.data.to = rotations.x + ' ' + rotations.y + ' ' + rotations.z;

camera.emit('rotateCamera');
camera.emit('moveCamera');


// HTML
<a-camera id="camera"
    look-controls
    wasd-controls="acceleration:200"
    animation__rotateCamera="property: rotation; startEvents: rotateCamera;"
    animation__moveCamera="property: position; startEvents: moveCamera;"
>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The data attribute should not be accessed directly, it is an internal variable for the component. The public API has to be used instead:

```
el.setAttribute('animation__rotateCamera', { to: foo });
```

More details in the docs:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem of the animation not happening. However, would you know why there is a frame at the beginning of my animation that looks like a graphic glitch.